Geometrically representing fraction divided by fraction and proportion?
Is there a geometric proof that shows this? Also accompanying algebraic proof?
$\frac {\frac {a}{b}} {\frac {c}{d}} =  \frac {a}{b} \frac {d}{c}$
I know a fraction can be geometrically represented as a triangle with the base meeting each leg at numerator and denominator length of the fraction. You can scale this by increasing length equally for both legs.
Including following picture as I suspect this represents perhaps above or a proportion when considering arms the legs of the triangle and the cross bar the base line between the resulting in two scalable fractions as lengths of each leg of the triangle:
${\frac {a}{b}} = {\frac {y}{x}}$

Ref link
Descartes showing similar where multiplication scales the other leg


Step 1.
Let $OP = \frac{a}{b}$, $OD = c$, $OC = d$, and the radius of the circle (green) is $1$.
Let
$$
CD\parallel MF \parallel NE
$$

Then we have:
$$
OF = \frac{d}{c} \quad\quad OE = \frac{c}{d}
$$
Step 2. Connect $PE$, and let $PE \parallel MQ$.
Then we have
$$
OQ = \frac{OP}{OE} = \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}
$$

Step 3. Connect $PE$ and $QF$.
We can prove that $QF\parallel PN$ (the proof is simple),
so we have
$$
OQ = OP \cdot OF = \frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{d}{c}
$$


Do you know if any of these propositions are in Euclid Elements?

What software did you use to make these graphics?

I posted a follow-up question on proportion here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4976846/geometric-representation-of-proportion
