Geometric representation of proportion?
How is $\frac a b = \frac y x$ represented geometrically? What happens when values $y,x$ vary? Is this a proposition in Euclid Elements?
I asked a question on a slightly different related topic here that was answered.
I know a fraction can be geometrically represented as a triangle with the base meeting each leg at numerator and denominator length of the fraction. You can scale this by increasing length equally for both legs.
Including following picture as I suspect this represents perhaps above or a proportion when considering arms the legs of the triangle and the cross bar the base line between the resulting in two scalable fractions as lengths of each leg of the triangle:

Ref link
Descartes showing similar where multiplication scales the other leg


Yes book 5 and 6 are all about ratios.
